# Issue in debugging a referenced dll even when pdb file exists in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, dll

I have 2 solutions, Source.sln and Client.sln both containing multiple projects.
After compiling **Source** I will copy all the dll and pdb to a **Lib** folder so that the projects in Client can use it. I added dll reference to this Lib folder for required projects in Client.
While debugging I couldn't step into the code of projects in source. I have referred so many SO and MSDN questions and did many changes. Apart from the steps performed below , could someone help me out to resolve this.

1. Clean and Build solution in Source. Copied new dll and pdb to Lib folder.
2. Enable Just my code is unchecked in debugger settings
3. Target framework matches in all projects
4. Symbol cache cleared
5. Debug info is set to full in Build-> Advanced Tab. Configuration is Debug
6. Deleted suo file from solution

Also tried to map the pdb at runtime from Debug-> Windows->Modules and for the specific dll. Getting an error like '*a matching symbol file was not found in this folder*'

Please note that I am running a Unit Test

Comment: Right-click the module in the Modules window and select "Symbol Load Information".  That tells you where it looked for the PDB, ensure it is there.

Comment: Yes, I checked it and it was saying that symbol not loaded. So I copied the pdb to the loaction where dll is present and from modules tab tried to load it , getting message like 'a matching symbol file was not found in this folder'. Multiple times I cleaned and build the sln , don't know why the symbol is not loading

Comment: Mapping new code from source control fixed the issue. Thanks for everyone's help